# Submitting a form using a custom button using HTML Web Components

Tags: html, web-component

I have defined a custom DOM element, but when placed inside a form, it does not submit it. How can I get the form to submit when I click the button?

```
<form action="/foo" method="GET">
  <my-button type="submit">click me</my-button>
</form>
```

This is the prototype configuration for the custom element:

```
myButton = Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype);
```

The template for the button looks like this:

```
<template>
  <button type="submit" id="button"><content></content></button>
</template>
```

Comment: There's a more modern approach available now than the accepted solution here - more info in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728792/submitting-a-form-using-a-custom-button-using-html-web-components/75021882#75021882) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Though event bubbling from shadow DOM to owner document is somehow possible, it’s [tricky](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#events) and in general is a wrong approach. Instead of hiding button into shadow, one should use `is=` attribute of button:

```
<form action="/foo" method="GET">
  <!--my-button type="submit">click me</my-button-->
  <!--                  ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓           -->  
  <button type="submit" is="my-button">click me</button>
</form>
```

[More info](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/custom-elements/).

Comment: Apple doesn't currently support the `is` attribute so this solution won't work for Safari.

Answer (score 7):

Came across this question today, but found a more modern alternative subsequently: web components can now be native form elements. There's a great read on the topic [here](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/web-components-can-now-be-native-form-elements-107c7a93386).

The long and the short of it is you can now associate custom components with a form, meaning they're included in the form's `elements` property - a `HTMLFormControlsCollection` of all the elements controlled by the form.

To do this, you need to add the following to your component:

```
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
  static get formAssociated() { return true; }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.internals = this.attachInternals();
  }
}
```

`this.internals` will then contain everything you need to interact with the form in question, e.g. `this.internals.form`, `this.internals.setFormValue()`, `this.internals.checkValidity()`.

For the submit button, you could, for example, use:

```
connectedCallback() {
  const { internals: { form } } = this;

  this.buttonEl.addEventListener('click', () => form.submit());
}
```

Comment: After trying this out it seems that his does not work in safari. Whenever I try to access the form attribute of the internals I get a `The operation is not supported` error. It seems like this is not currently supported by safari, or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: `caniuse.com` has it as fully supported as of Safari 16.4, but with a potential bug: https://caniuse.com/?search=elementinternals. Perhaps worth checking your version or having a read about the bug @Mercury? :)

Comment: @Mercury. What solved it for me was element-internals-polyfill.

Comment: @AmjadAbujamous Well It turns out that I was missing something very crucial but something that I completely missed at the time. In your component class you need to have the following variable set `static readonly formAssociated = true;` and then your component is associated with the form and you can access the form value of the internals. I hope that helps :-)

Comment: Tried this solution and form did submit, however the following `document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => { e.preventDefault(); alert('submit') })` cannot be triggered from web component button. Any direction?

Answer (score 0):

When your custom element extends a native element like `HTMLButtonElement`, you can no longer use a custom tag name like `<my-button>` (unfortunately). You have to use the native tag with the `is=` attribute:

```
<button type="submit" is="my-button">
```

If you do not extend a native element (called "type extension" in the spec), then you can use your custom tag name. [Type extension example in the spec](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#type-extension-example)

Comment: Why do you think that _“you can no longer use a custom tag name”_? Of course, you can. The problem is not with custom tag name. The problem is only with event bubbling.

Comment: If you know how to do a type extension (like the above example with `<button>`) with a custom tag name, I would love to see it. I don't think you can do it per the spec http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#type-extension-example

Comment: `document.registerElement('my-div', { prototype: MyPrototype, extends: 'div'});` and then use `<my-div>` or `document.createElement('my-div');`. `prototype` in the example above is optional, of course.

Comment: My opinion, I don't think that code is really a type extension. That will not support the semantics that are unique to <div>. It just puts
HTMLDivElement on the prototype chain, which does not do much.

Comment: btw here's a W3C bug on this having to use <button is="my-button">: https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=27976

Comment: I don’t get the point you want to prove. 1. It’s possible to extend a native element having custom tag name. 2. Whether one wants the extension to be mixed into the default behaviour, one should use `is=` syntax. 3. Whether the extension is intended to inherit the prototype, one has a freedom to choose. As you might see, in my answer I suggested to use `is=` syntax. That by no means entails the impossibility to extend elements giving them new names.

Comment: I think your 3 points are correct except in pt 1, you can use a custom tagname like `<my-button>`, but it will not give the capabilities of the native element you are trying to extend (like the OP discovered above), and therefore I do not see why you would even want to do this. More code for no reason if you do not use `<button is="my-button>`, like you correctly told him to do. I think this is actually a major drawback to custom elements as they are now specified. This has nothing to do with shadow DOM, by the way.