# Stencil Js, Submitting a form using a custom button

Tags: web-component, stenciljs

I have a custom web element (my-button) created with stencil js with shadowDom.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="field1"/>
  <input type="password" name="field2"/>

  <my-button type="submit">click me</my-button>
</form>
```

If i click "Enter" key in any of `<input>` fields - **onsubmit** event must be fired. But this doesn't happen if `<my-button>` uses shadowDom. Without shadowDom it works as a typical `<button type="submit">`.

Is there a way to make `<my-button>` with shadowDom works as native `<button type="submit">`?

Found few solutins here [Submitting a form using a custom button using HTML Web Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728792/submitting-a-form-using-a-custom-button-using-html-web-components) but the first solution is for native web elements (didn't find how to imlement the same in Stencil Js), the second solution doesn't work in Safari since Safari doesn't support **`is` attribute** so far.

Comment: Why do you want a shadowDOM on a simple button?

Comment: I need to prevent changing styles.  well, in general, my entire library of components uses shadowDom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main options I've seen:

1. Don't use Shadow DOM on that component. Stencil has an option for `scoped` styles which will prevent the styles from affecting anything outside the component but the style can be changed from outside.
2. Add a hidden native `button` element as a sibling of the web component in your component's `connectedCallback`. This preserves the advantages of using Shadow DOM but it does "leak" HTML which might become a problem.

The ideal solution would be for Stencil to support `formAssociated()`. There is an open issue (including a first implementation and workarounds from the great @johnjenkins), give it a thumbs up if you'd like to see it: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/2284